# Unit tests in Sonar

Tags: maven-2, sonarqube

Is it possible to run unit tests when a non-maven project is analyzed with Sonar, in Sonar light mode?

Comment: you want to have Sonar "light" include test coverage, but you don't have test coverage reports?  It might be possible to set up the Sonar "light" pom to run unit tests and generate coverage reports so that you could reuse them during the sonar step.  But what would be the point of such effort?  Are you running unit tests as part of your build?  If so, just run them with code coverage detection and generate the reports that Sonar needs directly.  There's no magic shortcut here.

Answer (score 1):

Sonar doesn't run unit tests. But it should be able to analyze existing unit tests reports. From [Reuse in Sonar unit test reports generated by other systems](http://www.sonarsource.org/reuse-in-sonar-unit-test-reports-generated-by-other-systems/):

> #### 2. Using Sonar in its full capability in an ANT environment
>
> If you are using ANT to build your
>   applications, the main weakness so far
>   in Sonar was that it did not allow to
>   display Unit tests results nor Code
>   coverage. I am sure that now you have
>   read the first use case, you know that
>   by using the
>   “-Dsonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports”
>   parameter, this limitation does not
>   exist anymore. You simply need to
>   specify where those reports to reuse
>   are going to be found, by using the
>   following properties :
>   sonar.cobertura.reportPath,
>   sonar.clover.reportPath,
>   sonar.surefire.reportsPath...

Comment: Yes, I read about reuse unit tests reports, but the problem is that I don't have them. I have a multi module project, each module has an project.xml file (like in maven 1.x); and I have to analyze this project in Sonar. I managed to get the some metrics with sonar light mode, but for some modules I have to get code coverage...I have no idea know can I do this.